# print_r() prints out only 150 elements in array

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I have an array `$product_urls` containing 200 elements.

**Problem:** When I do a `print_r($product_urls)`, PHP prints out an array containing 150 elements, and the output appears to be truncated because its missing the closing `)`. I checked the HTML source code generated and it is indeed truncated at the 150th element. `count($product_urls)` gives `200`.

This is puzzling. I'm using a PHP framework called Laravel. Any ideas?

**PHP Code**

```
echo "<pre>";
echo count($product_urls);
print_r($product_urls);
```

**Output**

```
200Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-With-Girl-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2409264
    [1] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Dork-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2483696
    [2] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Kasabian-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2428327
    [3] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Long-Sleeve-Crew-Neck-T-Shirt-With-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2548469
    [4] => http://www.example.com/Scotch-Soda/Scotch-And-Soda-T-Shirt-In-Washed-Cotton/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2496980

    //...

    [147] => http://www.example.com/BePriv/Be-Priv-90210-Tiffany-T-shirt-Exclusive-To-mysite-UK/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2262271
    [148] => http://www.example.com/The-Quiet-Life/The-Quiet-Life-Start-Making-Sense-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2200659
    [149] => http://www.example.com/The-Quiet-Life/The-Quiet-Life-Camera-Statue-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2200660
```

**Entire Print_r Output** *(using Raheel Shan's method)*

```
200Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-With-Girl-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2409264
    [1] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Dork-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2483696
    [2] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Kasabian-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2428327
    [3] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Long-Sleeve-Crew-Neck-T-Shirt-With-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2548469
    [4] => http://www.example.com/Scotch-Soda/Scotch-And-Soda-T-Shirt-In-Washed-Cotton/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2496980
    [5] => http://www.example.com/Scotch-Soda/Scotch-And-Soda-T-Shirt-with-Block-Hoop/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2496983
    [6] => http://www.example.com/Carhartt/Carhartt-Marker-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2453973
    [7] => http://www.example.com/Levis-Vintage/Levis-Vintage-T-Shirt-1950-Sportswear/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2270995
    [8] => http://www.example.com/The-Quiet-Life/The-Quiet-Life-Camera-Club-T-shirt-Bike/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2494276
    [9] => http://www.example.com/Reclaimed-Vintage/Reclaimed-Vintage-Vest-with-Paisley-Peace-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2533797
    [10] => http://www.example.com/Supreme-Being/Supremebeing-White-Canvas-Project-T-Shirt-Mr-Jago/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2363025
    [11] => http://www.example.com/Reclaimed-Vintage/Reclaimed-Vintage-T-Shirt-with-Tye-Dye-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2533633
    [12] => http://www.example.com/Emporio-Armani/Emporio-Armani-Pure-Cotton-Crew-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1999130
    [13] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Layered-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2457845
    [14] => http://www.example.com/Diesel/Diesel-T-Shirt-With-Stamp-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2441057
    [15] => http://www.example.com/Diesel/Diesel-T-Shirt-With-Label-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2441126
    [16] => http://www.example.com/Lee/Lee-T-Shirt-With-Play-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2425959
    [17] => http://www.example.com/Lee/Lee-T-Shirt-With-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2426033
    [18] => http://www.example.com/Lee/Lee-Grandad-Top/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2425415
    [19] => http://www.example.com/Nike-Skateboard/Nike-Skateboarding-T-Shirt-Speciman-Icon/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2445650
    [20] => http://www.example.com/American-Apparel/American-Apparel-Muscle-Tank/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2503093
    [21] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Safety-Pin-Skull-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2398683
    [22] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Clash-Long-Sleeve-Top/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2398419
    [23] => http://www.example.com/American-Apparel/American-Apparel-Helvetica-T-Shirt-ZZ/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2502997
    [24] => http://www.example.com/American-Apparel/American-Apparel-Helvetica-T-Shirt-XX/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2502998
    [25] => http://www.example.com/American-Apparel/American-Apparel-3/4-Sleeve-Raglan-Top/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2503354
    [26] => http://www.example.com/Nike-Skateboard/Nike-Skateboarding-Laces-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2445588
    [27] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Animal-Print-Girl-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2410231
    [28] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Oxford-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2480313
    [29] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Stripe-T-Shirt-With-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2420685
    [30] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Flag-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2484341
    [31] => http://www.example.com/Cheap-Monday/Cheap-Monday-Stripe-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2379675
    [32] => http://www.example.com/Cheap-Monday/Cheap-Monday-Tor-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2379596
    [33] => http://www.example.com/Hilfiger-Denim/Hilfiger-Denim-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2309725
    [34] => http://www.example.com/Franklin-Marshall/Franklin-Marshall-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2360997
    [35] => http://www.example.com/Denham/Denham-T-Shirt-Barnum-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2302619
    [36] => http://www.example.com/Analog/Analog-Baseball-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2445332
    [37] => http://www.example.com/Analog/Analog-T-shirt-Astro-Dot/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2445516
    [38] => http://www.example.com/Adidas-Originals/Adidas-Originals-T-Shirt-Stencil-Trefoil/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2447712
    [39] => http://www.example.com/Adidas-Originals/Adidas-Originals-T-Shirt-Fine-Stripe-Trefoil-Logo/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2447613
    [40] => http://www.example.com/Adidas-Originals/Adidas-Originals-Superstar-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2446200
    [41] => http://www.example.com/Adidas-Originals/Adidas-Originals-Originals-Icon-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2446130
    [42] => http://www.example.com/Adidas-Originals/Adidas-Originals-T-Shirt-Trefoil-Rasta/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2349590
    [43] => http://www.example.com/Adidas-Originals/Adidas-Originals-T-Shirt-Masking-Tape/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2349584
    [44] => http://www.example.com/Adidas-Originals/Adidas-Originals-Superstar-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2446162
    [45] => http://www.example.com/Adidas-Originals/Adidas-Originals-Daily-Hustle-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2349550
    [46] => http://www.example.com/G-Star/G-Star-T-Shirt-Elwood-Restany-Motorbike-Logo/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2258870
    [47] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Long-Sleeved-T-Shirt-With-Grandad-Collar-In-Pique-Jersey/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2395254
    [48] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Basic-Scoop-Neck-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1397435
    [49] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-With-Racer-Back/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2457514
    [50] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Varsity-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2484233
    [51] => http://www.example.com/Lazy-Oaf/Lazy-Oaf-Log-In-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2366658
    [52] => http://www.example.com/Ezra-Wine/Ezra-Wine-Medusa-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2383291
    [53] => http://www.example.com/Lazy-Oaf/Lazy-Oaf-Dropout-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2366535
    [54] => http://www.example.com/Lazy-Oaf/Lazy-Oaf-T-Shirt-with-Tongue-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2366527
    [55] => http://www.example.com/Lazy-Oaf/Lazy-Oaf-Going-to-Hell-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2366525
    [56] => http://www.example.com/Denham/Denham-T-Shirt-With-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2511832
    [57] => http://www.example.com/55DSL/55DSL-Hula-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2375696
    [58] => http://www.example.com/55DSL/55DSL-Sky-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2375931
    [59] => http://www.example.com/Selected/Selected-Stripe-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2504193
    [60] => http://www.example.com/Selected/Selected-Stripe-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2504191
    [61] => http://www.example.com/Selected/Selected-T-shirt-with-Double-Layer/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2504184
    [62] => http://www.example.com/Selected/Selected-T-Shirt-with-Double-Layer/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2504135
    [63] => http://www.example.com/Denham/Denham-T-Shirt-With-Scissor-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2511889
    [64] => http://www.example.com/Replay/Replay-T-Shirt-With-V-Neck/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2423227
    [65] => http://www.example.com/Lazy-Oaf/Lazy-Oaf-Patches-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2366648
    [66] => http://www.example.com/Lazy-Oaf/Lazy-Oaf-T-Shirt-with-FC-Stripe/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2366533
    [67] => http://www.example.com/Lazy-Oaf/Lazy-Oaf-T-Shirt-with-Bandana-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2366528
    [68] => http://www.example.com/Lazy-Oaf/Lazy-Oaf-End-is-Nigh-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2366425
    [69] => http://www.example.com/Christopher-Shannon/Christopher-Shannon-Kidda-Laurel-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2323166
    [70] => http://www.example.com/The-Quiet-Life/The-Quiet-Life-T-shirt-With-Cosmo-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2494015
    [71] => http://www.example.com/Selected/Selected-T-Shirt-with-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2365377
    [72] => http://www.example.com/Selected/Selected-Fleck-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2412803
    [73] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Aztec-Animal-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2412464
    [74] => http://www.example.com/Worn-By/Worn-By-Neon-Tribal-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2305500
    [75] => http://www.example.com/Worn-By/Worn-By-Hell-Yeah-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2305595
    [76] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Razor-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2303944
    [77] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-All-Over-Paisley-Print-And-Contrast-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2405169
    [78] => http://www.example.com/River-Island/River-Island-Vest-with-Surf-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2391220
    [79] => http://www.example.com/Selected/Selected-Stripe-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2299829
    [80] => http://www.example.com/Selected/Selected-Stripe-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2299786
    [81] => http://www.example.com/River-Island/River-Island-Motel-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2398677
    [82] => http://www.example.com/River-Island/River-Island-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2398569
    [83] => http://www.example.com/River-Island/River-Island-Vest-with-Shanghai-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2391145
    [84] => http://www.example.com/Cheap-Monday/Cheap-Monday-Mond-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2379599
    [85] => http://www.example.com/Esprit/Esprit-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2249197
    [86] => http://www.example.com/Reclaimed-Vintage/Reclaimed-Vintage-Russian-Naval-T-Shirts/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2274797
    [87] => http://www.example.com/Worn-By/Worn-By-Zebra-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2305605
    [88] => http://www.example.com/Savant/Savant-Fresh-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2187734
    [89] => http://www.example.com/New-Love-Club/New-Love-Club-Nude-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2031399
    [90] => http://www.example.com/Your-Eyes-Lie/Your-Eyes-Lie-All-for-You-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1996304
    [91] => http://www.example.com/People-Tree/People-Tree-Sydney-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2072528
    [92] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-With-Aztec-Design/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2351895
    [93] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-With-All-Over-Geo-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2373754
    [94] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Stripe-T-Shirt-With-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2257136
    [95] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Stripe-T-Shirt-With-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2257138
    [96] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Crew-Long-Sleeve-Top-With-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1874647
    [97] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Flower-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2373623
    [98] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Crew-Neck-T-Shirt-With-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1605761
    [99] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Skull-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2483379
    [100] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Sex-Pistols-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2420836
    [101] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Aztec-Girl-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2409391
    [102] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Camo-Print-And-Chambray-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2408949
    [103] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-In-There-Like-Swimwear-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2404269
    [104] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Camo-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2336996
    [105] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-All-Over-Pattern/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2367036
    [106] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Giant-Aztec-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2373696
    [107] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Crew-Neck-T-Shirt-With-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2378610
    [108] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-All-Over-Space-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2368944
    [109] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-3/4-Sleeve-Top-In-Waffle-Jersey/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2395846
    [110] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-With-Fluro-Stripe/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2352422
    [111] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-With-David-Bowie-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2393776
    [112] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Shoulder-Patch/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2364066
    [113] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Deep-V-Neck/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2428120
    [114] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Shoulder-Patch/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2375275
    [115] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Mystic-Eye-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2407356
    [116] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Aztec-Hem-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2371017
    [117] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-All-Over-Hula-Girl-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2407724
    [118] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Colorado-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2352880
    [119] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-All-Over-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2412241
    [120] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Stripe-T-Shirt-With-Flag-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2363870
    [121] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-With-Tape-And-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2351801
    [122] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-USA-Flag-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2352165
    [123] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-All-Over-And-Double-Layer-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2364006
    [124] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Long-Sleeve-Top-With-Deep-V/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1873299
    [125] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Stripe-T-Shirt-With-Two-Tone-Jersey-Marl/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2368253
    [126] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Stripe-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2373649
    [127] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-All-Over-Aztec-Stripe/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2405360
    [128] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-All-Over-Print-And-Contrast-Neck-Trim/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2412415
    [129] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Mask-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2412477
    [130] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Bill-And-Ted-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2320906
    [131] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Dip-Dye-Hem/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2373764
    [132] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Stripe-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2250612
    [133] => http://www.example.com/Solid/Solid-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2354420
    [134] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Printed-Woven-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2394637
    [135] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Printed-Woven-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2375274
    [136] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Fish-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2269490
    [137] => http://www.example.com/Bellfield/Bellfield-Aztec-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2383222
    [138] => http://www.example.com/Esprit/Esprit-T-Shirt-with-Surf-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2249271
    [139] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Rolled-Sleeves/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2412631
    [140] => http://www.example.com/Reclaimed-Vintage/Reclaimed-Vintage-Russian-Naval-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2274815
    [141] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Floral-Pocket-And-Yoke/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2199554
    [142] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-T-Shirt-With-Eagle-Sunset-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2198894
    [143] => http://www.example.com/Death-By-Zero/Death-by-Zero-Primal-Urge-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2352921
    [144] => http://www.example.com/Death-By-Zero/Death-by-Zero-Nights-in-Manhattan-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2353016
    [145] => http://www.example.com/Death-By-Zero/Death-by-Zero-Hit-the-Ground-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2353013
    [146] => http://www.example.com/River-Island/River-Island-T-Shirt-with-Jazzy-Jeff-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2367043
    [147] => http://www.example.com/BePriv/Be-Priv-90210-Tiffany-T-shirt-Exclusive-To-mysite-UK/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2262271
    [148] => http://www.example.com/The-Quiet-Life/The-Quiet-Life-Start-Making-Sense-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2200659
    [149] => http://www.example.com/The-Quiet-Life/The-Quiet-Life-Camera-Statue-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2200660
    [150] => http://www.example.com/Denim-Supply-by-Ralph-Lauren/Denim-Supply-by-Ralph-Lauren-Shield-Logo-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2214188
    [151] => http://www.example.com/Clubbed-to-Death/Clubbed-to-Death-Tie-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2342946
    [152] => http://www.example.com/Clubbed-to-Death/Clubbed-to-Death-RocknRoll-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2342949
    [153] => http://www.example.com/Clubbed-to-Death/Clubbed-to-Death-Priviledge-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2343095
    [154] => http://www.example.com/Clubbed-to-Death/Clubbed-to-Death-Ibiza-Rocks-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2342877
    [155] => http://www.example.com/Clubbed-to-Death/Clubbed-to-Death-I-Heart-Cream-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2343085
    [156] => http://www.example.com/Suit/Suit-Multistripe-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2245305
    [157] => http://www.example.com/Suit/Suit-Marl-Stripe-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2245454
    [158] => http://www.example.com/Suit/Suit-Block-Colour-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2245089
    [159] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Stripe-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2250508
    [160] => http://www.example.com/Worn-By/Worn-By-Rotten-Food-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2085029
    [161] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Stripe-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2250577
    [162] => http://www.example.com/Jack-Jones-Vintage/Jack-Jones-Vintage-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2217454
    [163] => http://www.example.com/Minimum/Minimum-Maidai-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2243906
    [164] => http://www.example.com/American-Apparel/American-Apparel-Oversized-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2339752
    [165] => http://www.example.com/Selected/Selected-Jimmy-Hendrix-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2191026
    [166] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-With-Leaf-Print-And-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2261785
    [167] => http://www.example.com/Insight/Insight-Giddget-Must-Die-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2045641
    [168] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Bramford-Pocket-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2304093
    [169] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Legs-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2303942
    [170] => http://www.example.com/WESC/WESC-Puzzle-Overlay-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2187520
    [171] => http://www.example.com/WESC/WESC-Icon-And-Stripes-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2187451
    [172] => http://www.example.com/Revolution/Revolution-Stripe-Pocket-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2247329
    [173] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Stripe-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2250507
    [174] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Striped-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2303946
    [175] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Square-Pocket-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2304086
    [176] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Scream-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2303943
    [177] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Rest-in-Peace-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2303852
    [178] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Low-V-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2304183
    [179] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Gradient-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2303945
    [180] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Basic-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2304260
    [181] => http://www.example.com/Religion/Religion-Rumours-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2304269
    [182] => http://www.example.com/Esprit/Esprit-Pocket-Marl-Crew-Neck-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2257627
    [183] => http://www.example.com/Sin-Star/Sin-Star-Live-Fast-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2274387
    [184] => http://www.example.com/Savant/Savant-Sofa-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2187666
    [185] => http://www.example.com/Savant/Savant-Puzzle-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2187664
    [186] => http://www.example.com/Your-Eyes-Lie/Your-Eyes-Lie-Navo-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1996309
    [187] => http://www.example.com/Your-Eyes-Lie/Your-Eyes-Lie-Navo-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1996212
    [188] => http://www.example.com/Esprit/Esprit-Pocket-Marl-Crew-Neck-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2255386
    [189] => http://www.example.com/Your-Eyes-Lie/Your-Eyes-Lie-Ethnic-Animal-Vest/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=1996312
    [190] => http://www.example.com/Polo-Ralph-Lauren/Polo-Ralph-Lauren-Anchor-Print-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2192627
    [191] => http://www.example.com/Savant/Savant-Hello-Boys-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2187661
    [192] => http://www.example.com/Jack-Jones-Vintage/Jack-Jones-Vintage-Surf-Shop-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2217196
    [193] => http://www.example.com/Replay/Replay-Replay-T-Shirt-college-logo/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2117989
    [194] => http://www.example.com/Esprit/Esprit-Reverse-Pocket-Stripe-Crew-Neck-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2183750
    [195] => http://www.example.com/Sin-Star/Sin-Star-Kill-Graphic-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2274447
    [196] => http://www.example.com/Sin-Star/Sin-Star-Destroy-Graphic-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2274445
    [197] => http://www.example.com/J-Lindeberg/J-Lindeberg-Scoop-Neck-T-Shirt/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2228059
    [198] => http://www.example.com/J-Lindeberg/J-Lindeberg-Fine-Stripe-T-Shirt-with-Pocket/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2227948
    [199] => http://www.example.com/mysite/mysite-Vest-With-Eagle-Print/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2099899
)
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, did you try just looping through the entries and printing them separately?

Comment: What does var_dump() give you?

Comment: Do you `preg_match` against a `regex` and your `regex` bumps intro someting?

Comment: Can we have a copy of the `$product_urls` for futher testing and which version of PHP are you using

Comment: @bdares Looping through the array and echoing the element prints out all the 200 elements. Somehow when doing this looping together with `print_r`, `print_r` now prints out all 200 elements!

Comment: @Duniyadnd `var_dump` stops at element 135.

Comment: Looping through the array only without doing a `print_r()` gives me 164 elements from the loop.

Comment: do this for test purpose $output = print_r($array, true);
this will store output in variable $output then print_r or vardump $output

Comment: I have 2 questions: (1) How are you through the array (can you post the code)? (2) How do you populate the array with the product urls?

Comment: take a look at this question similar problem already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171289/whats-the-maximum-number-of-keys-for-an-array-in-php

Comment: @Baba Sorry I cant figure out how to output the entire array in a way that you can just use it directly yourself and still contain all 200 elements. I have included the `print_r` output in original post.

Comment: @raheelshan This outputs all 200 elements of the array properly! What happened?

Comment: Do you happen to have XDebug or any similar PHP modules loaded in your environment. I know XDebug overrides the default var_dump in order to limit its output and to beautify it with HTML.

Comment: @LeonelMachava (1)The original problem was with `print_r($arrayname)`. Now it seems that looping through the array using a `foreach` loop and echoing each element has problem printing all 200 elements, along with `var_dump()`. (2) The array was populated using a `foreach` loop that iterates through an object (SimpleHttpDom).

Comment: @MihaiStancu XDebug does not appear in `phpinfo()`. I'm not sure if the Laravel framework has something similar.

Comment: Interesting! Silly question perhaps, but is php error and notice  reporting turned on?

Comment: Unless Laravel is implemented as a PHP module it would not be able to override PHP functions.

Comment: I have `report_zend_debug` turned On in phpinfo. Not sure if thats xdebug...

Comment: @Makita From `phpinfo()` under `local values`, `error_reporting` is `-1`, and `display_errors` is `On`.

Comment: i dont know but isnt it a an alternative

Comment: @raheelshan Yes its a good alternative :)

Comment: @Nyxynyx - xDebug and Zend Debugger are separate products, but they do similar things. I don't know the Zend Debugger, but it's quite plausible that it could be truncating your `print_r()` output. xDebug does this kind of thing, so I don't see why Zend Debugger wouldn't. Definitely worth investigating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The array is obviously correct, or at least it is 200 elements long.

The problem then is that Laravel probably does not expect you to shoot output using echo or var_dump or print_r, and "directly output'ed HTML" is likely to smash against some kind of output processor unless you leverage Laravel's Logger class.

It might be a coincidence, but your output size seems to fall around 16 Kb, which is the preferred buffer size of several processors/beautifiers/HTML cleaners.

What happens if you array_slice, say, the first 20 elements off the beginning of your array? Do only 130 elements get displayed, or do you still see 150 (more or less) elements?

Edit: if you really have to use echo, print_r or any "non-Laravel" method to output something quick&dirty, you may almost certainly do it like this:

```
  // Open another output buffering context
  ob_start();

  print_r($WHATEVER);

  $_output = ob_get_contents();
  // Destroy the context so that Laravel's none the wiser
  ob_end_clean();

  $_fp = fopen("/tmp/myfile.txt", "w");
  fwrite($_fp, $_output);
  fclose($_fp);
  // Remove awkward traces
  unset($_fp, $_output);
```

You may also encapsulate the last part into a function of your own, so that you can write

```
  // in helpers.php
  function myObStop($file, $mode = 'a') {
      $_output = ob_get_contents();
      // Destroy the context so that Laravel's none the wiser
      ob_end_clean();

      $_fp = fopen($file, $mode);
      fwrite($_fp, $_output);
      fclose($_fp);
  }

  ob_start();
  print "Whatever";
  myObStop('/tmp/myfile.txt', 'w');
```

and leave Laravel executing after that. But I **strongly** advise to exploit Logger instead:

```
  http://laravel.com/docs/logging#logging
```

Comment: After slicing off the first 20 elements, `count()` gives 180, `print_r()` still prints out 150 elements.

Comment: Heh. So there's something that truncates your output, and it's not PHP -- it can only be Laravel. I'm adding a butcher's option to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When I test arrays I use this.

I'm pretty sure this is a default helper function called: dd()

```
$array;  // That is 200 elements long.

var_dump($array);
die(); // Prevents html from being rendered if executed in the controller or model.
```

Every time I try to do this in my view it gets messed up by the HTML like Iserni said.